# Whole site caching on MediaTemple's ProCDN - cname setup

Tags: media, cdn, mediatemple

Am unable to properly configure ProCDN to point to my website's root.

I have a completely static website: http://thaifood-recipes.com no PHP, MySQL, etc. Just static HTML, images, CSS, etc.

I have followed the Getting Started with ProCDN guide at MT, but instead of offloading some content from a subdomain, like cdn.thaifood-recipes.com, I am wanting the whole site to just be served, as its all static, cacheable content.

MT Support dragging the heels getting back to me with a direct answer.

Any ideas or alternative CDNs to do the same thing if ProCDN won't allow?

Cheers,

Leon Stafford

leonstafford.com

Answer (score 1):

You can't serve an entire site from ProCDN, even if it's static HTML. Your web server at the origin needs to serve the pages themselves. ProCDN is for media such as images, CSS etc.

Comment: the alternative is to use "cdn.domain.com" as origin and serve the CDN content at "www.domain.com"? Will this retain URL structure for a site with "www.domain.com/page/" , not "www.domain.com/page.html"?

Answer (score 0):

[Cloudflare](http://www.cloudflare.com/) offers a free service and you could also try [Google's Free CDN...](http://code.google.com/speed/pss/)